# Will reputation points be decreased if I close my own question?

Tags: support, reputation, questions, vote-to-close

If I close my answer then reputation point will be decreased ? I want to close my question because it is related to my another question. And for that question I have posted my own answer to my own question so if I don't close the question also for that question I have to give the same answer.What should I do for that ?

Comment: Do you mean *delete* or *vote to close*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you vote to close, voting is still available and rep continues to count (in both directions).

If you delete your question, then at the next recalc, rep gained from it will be removed. This will also apply, I believe, to any answers on the question. (And note that after a certain number of answers -- the exact count eludes me -- you won't be able to delete the question anymore.)

Answer (score 1):

Close? no, but you'll need 4 more votes from others. Delete? Yes, but your rep will not drop immediately. If you delete a question or answer that earned up-votes, your rep will drop during the next recalc, which is scheduled at some point before the sun explodes again.

(after all, something had to go boom to make the sun the sun, yes?)